# Create a relationship between tables based on concatenated fields

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to create a relationship between two tables based on multiple fields. In Excel, I would use concatenate to combine the field names into one unique value to do my vlookup. For example, I would lookup City and Department using a combined CityDepartment. How can I make this link similarly in Access tables? If I create a relationship just between City and just between Department I do not get that unique CityDepartment.

If I wanted to do a JOIN on multiple fields...why wouldn't something like this work? I am getting a syntax error.

```
SELECT HRBI.ID (For all fields)
FROM HRBI 
LEFT JOIN MINC
ON HRBI.PayGroupRegionCode = MINC.Region AND HRBI.PayGroupCountryDesc = MINC.Country AND HRBI.[BusinessLvl1(Group)Code] = MINC.BusinessGroup;
```

Comment: There is no reason why a relationship should not use two fields (columns) as long as both will always contain data.

Comment: Where do I make the unique combination? At the Query level?

Comment: Use the relationship window. You can also use a query,

Comment: You might like to see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12145258/distinct-row-based-on-two-fields

Comment: Can you take a look at my JOIN code? What's wrong with the syntax?

Comment: Do you not have use of MS Access query design window? Why left join when all you want is matches?

Comment: I have use of query design window, but I am not sure what you mean...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89184/discussion-between-fionnuala-and-user1813558).

Comment: I'm still seeking help on this one. Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to combine the two fields by creating the relationships in Design View. I then created a query and edited the SQL to the following:

```
  SELECT HRBI.PayGroupCountryDesc, HRBI.[BusinessLvl1(Group)Code], MINC.Country, MINC.BusinessGroup, MINC.MINCPercentageofSalary
    FROM HRBI LEFT JOIN MINC ON (HRBI.[BusinessLvl1(Group)Code] = MINC.BusinessGroup) AND (HRBI.[PayGroupCountryDesc] = MINC.[Country])
    ORDER BY HRBI.PayGroupCountryDesc;
```

No issues after that.