# Delete Records from Table Before Delete Trigger

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I know that in MSSQL when you load a trigger onto a table, that you have access to a "cache table" of the record(s) to be operated on (Update, Insert, Delete).

Is there a similar mechanism to utilize from Access?  If not, if i want to enforce a 1:1-M from a base table to the Join Tables, how would i do this?

Tried using their "Oh so useful" Relationship Schema, but since i cant find a "unique" index for the PK's i setup and indexed, i cant use the trickle-down delete portion of the Enforce Integrity.  Has the "rarely" seen, which seems to be common for me, Relationship status of "Indeterminate".

## Design

### Table1 (base table):

#### Fields:

- gid
- nm
- (more fields)

#### Indexes:

- gid + nm (unique identification - gid is not AutoNumber)
- gid

### Table 2 (join table):

#### Fields:

- gid
- cid
- (more fields)

#### Indexes:

- gid + cid (unique identification)
- gid
- cid

## Trigger Idea:

### Delete (BeforeDelete Trigger)

1. If (table1.gid is deleted) then `Delete * From Table2 Where gid=delete.id`

   - Where `delete` is the cache table
2. Continue validation until all tables have been properly updated/deleted of the entries for the gid from the base table

## Edit 2012-09-04 @ 12:20pm

Ok Here is the Data-Macro i have right now, its probably syntactically sloppy but what i have deduced so far from my readings online.  Is there anything i should be aware of, or expect, when using this format?  And yes `deletegroup` is a globabl method posted in a Module.

[image: Before Delete Data-Macro]

The end-users will be using Runtime Access, should this trigger be hampered in any way by a runtime environment vs a full-version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The natural next step in macros is to provide a model for business
>   rules. Data macros allow developers to attach logic to record/table
>   events (similar to SQL triggers). This means you write logic in one
>   place and all forms and code that updates those tables inherit that
>   logic. Here are a few data macro scenarios you might find in a typical
>   Donations Management database:

[Access 2010 data macros (similar to triggers)](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-access/archive/2009/08/13/access-2010-data-macros-similar-to-triggers.aspx)

Alternatively, for cascade delete, considering setting up relationships as per my comment to your previous post: [Reference to composite primary key in Access 2007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11730619/reference-to-composite-primary-key-in-access-2007/11737106#11737106)

Comment: that would be the `gid + cid` indexes, but the Join Table only has one of the fields of either indexes on the tables.

Comment: Been looking at the other link, but it talks in generics and not alot of details about how to operate with the `old` and `new` cache tables.  I ultimately want to delete records from `Table2` where the `old.gid` is contained in `Table2`.  I dont want to interrupt the deletion just want to design a trigger mechanism that will delete from the other Join Tables.