# Create a relationship between two tables using two fields

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am trying to link two separate tables based on a `City` and `State` field. I originally had a combined field of `City, State` however, I thought it was a best practice to have these two fields broken out. My problem is I do not know how to make the relationship link between two tables using two fields. If I link just the `City` without the `State` this is incorrect, because many cities share the same name across multiple states. I thought I *could* leave  the `City` and `State` as separate fields and create a third field `City, State` for the purposes of linking the two tables, but my guess is there might be a better way of doing this. I attempted a `Lookup`, but I wasn't sure if this was the correct and/or best route. Is the combined CityState field the correct way to achieve this link? I assume I would still, later on, be able to Query on just `City` or just `State`.

Thank you.

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11730619/reference-to-composite-primary-key-in-access-2007/11737106#11737106

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an intermediate table with `City` and `State` fields. This will allow you to pull the state name by the value in the `City` field. The combined field is NOT recommended as this is unnecessarily repeating data on a record.